# End reading the file when a negative number is reached in c

Tags: c

i'am new in c programming, and i have a problem that i cant solve, is any one can help me? 
This is the condition, 
i am practicing my self in 'file handling in C Language',
and what i want to do is count the number of a float number from a file, for example,
the input file contains:

1.0 0.0 4.5 74.0 1.33 0.0 -1.0 1.0

OUTPUT WILL BE:
6

so, what i want is count how many numbers contains the input file and 
after the -1.0 is reached, the count is over, and -1.0 will not include in counting. or -1.0 will be the end of file. how can i do that? i am using C PROGRAMMING LANGUAGE.

i have a little code, but it only count the number until the EOF is reached.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
  FILE *f=fopen("input.in","r");
  int c,count;

  if(f==NULL){ return 1; }   

  c = getc(f);    
  while(c != EOF){
    if (c  == ' ') 
    count++; 
    c = getc(f); 
  }fclose(f);

  printf ("Number of Cases: %d\n", count);
  return 0;
}
```

It only count the number of input separated by space but not stop if -1.0 is reached.

Thanks!

Comment: Read about [scanf(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/scanf.3.html) and the number of items it is returning. Compile with all warnings and debug info (e.g. `gcc -Wall -g`). **Use the debugger** (e.g. `gdb`).

Comment: `double x; while (scanf("%lf", &x) == 1 && x != -1.0) count++;` (after 8 hours, if still stuck here is an idea.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's look at the main loop of your program:

```
c = getc(f);    
while (c != EOF) {
    if (c  == ' ') count++; 
    c = getc(f); 
}
```

Clearly you are testing for, and therefore finding the EOF case, but where in this loop do you test for a negative input?  Answer: you don't so clearly you aren't going to find it.  Others have suggested using a function other than `getc()` *which reads 1 character at a time (say scanf)*.  But, for illustrative purposes let's stay with your basic outline:

```
c = getc(f);    
while (c != EOF) {
    if (c == '-') break;       /* saw a minus, must be the end */
    if (c  == ' ') count++;    /* saw a space, must be a gap between numbers, count that */
    c = getc(f); 
}
```

Note that while better this still isn't quite correct -- imagine this input `1.0 2.0 3.0` you will count the two inter-number spaces, but you don't count the last number.  Also you don't handle the case of multiple spaces between numbers (`1.0      2.0    3.0   -5)`.

```
int ws = 1;                               /* white space mode is on */
while ((c = getc(f)) != EOF) {
    if (ws && (c == ' ')) continue;       /* more white space, just skip */
    if (ws && (c == '-')) break;          /* white space ended with a minus, done */
    if (ws) ++count;                      /* white space ended, start of new  positive number */
    ws = (c == ' ');                      /* are we starting whitespace mode again? */
}
```

Imagine various input strings and walk through this code a line at a time in your mind.  If you find a problem, think how you could solve it.   Repeat.   *Hint: -1 vs -2*

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
  FILE *f=fopen("input.in","r");
  int count=0;
  double x;

  if(f==NULL){ return 1; }

  while(fscanf(f, "%lf", &x)==1 && !(x < 0)){
    count++; 
  }
  fclose(f);

  printf ("Number of Cases: %d\n", count);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this! i already fix my problem by my own but this answer give me another solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(){

FILE* f = fopen("a.in","r");
float ld;
int c=0,i;
double values[100];

if(f == NULL){
    printf("File not found!");
    return;
}

while(fscanf(f,"%f\n",&ld) == 1){    
    if(ld == -1.0){ 
        printf("Number of Cases: %d\n",c);
    }
    c++;
}fclose(f);
return 0;
```